# How to adjust keyboard map for the TTY to support Control + Function Keys?

Tags: keyboard, tty

How can I create or edit a TTY keymap so that it passes along Control + Function Keys, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> ? If this is not possible, please explain why not?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, without a GUI.

Background: It is my assumption that my TTY is not generating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> because it doesn't show up when I run `cat -v` and press the key combination. I have heard from others that the cause is the limited TTY keymap. I don't know if this is possible, but a definitive answer one way or the other would be appreciated.